# Explain this Elixir binary search implementation

Tags: elixir

Good day. I have some `Elixir` code that does a `Binary search`. I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind it. Could someone explain the logic behind each `function`?

```
@spec search(tuple, integer) :: {:ok, integer} | :not_found
def search({}, _key), do: :not_found
def search(numbers, key), do: search(numbers, key, 0, tuple_size(numbers) - 1)
def search(numbers, key, 0, 1) when elem(numbers, 0) == key, do: {:ok, 0}
def search(numbers, key, min, max) when div(max - min, 2) == 0 and elem(numbers, max) == key, do: {:ok, max}
def search(numbers, key, min, max) do
  middle = div(max - min, 2) + min
  value = elem(numbers, middle)
  cond do
    value == key -> {:ok, middle}
    middle == max or middle == min -> :not_found
    value < key -> search(numbers, key, middle, max)
    value > key -> search(numbers, key, min,   
  end
end
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because “explain me how it works” is an off-topic on this site. Try to ask this question on https://elixirforum.com instead.

Comment: ok, I spent some time to respond...anyway  @AlekseiMatiushkin is right.

Answer (score 4):

Elixir uses pattern matching to choose which function to call. In your example, different search function are implemented to make the code more readable.
So starting from the first (the order in which they are declared is important):

```
def search({}, _key), do: :not_found
```

if the tuple is empty return the atom `:not_found`

```
def search(numbers, key), do: search(numbers, key, 0, tuple_size(numbers) - 1)
```

General case (probably this is the called function, it calls another clause passing the range (0 - size) since the quick sort works on a range of the original tuple

```
def search(numbers, key, 0, 1) when elem(numbers, 0) == key, do: {:ok, 0}
```

When called with the range 0, 1 (that means 1 element) and the element is what you are searching...returns `{:ok, 0}` (don't know why 0, should be `key`)

```
def search(numbers, key, min, max) when div(max - min, 2) == 0 and elem(numbers, max) == key, do: {:ok, max}
```

In this case it matches the last element of the sublist (min to max) and if it is key it returns it.

```
def search(numbers, key, min, max) do
```

This is the general implementation that recursively calls the other functions based on the binary search algorithm logic.

So instead of having multiple if/switch inside one function, elixir promote the use of different function with different guards/clauses to make the core more readable.

Comment: what's the point or logic of this divider? `div(max - min, 2)` from this function? `def search(numbers, key, min, max) when div(max - min, 2) == 0 and elem(numbers, max) == key, do: {:ok, max}`

Comment: Actually I don't know, probably is just an optimisation that saves some recursive calls.